# Selecting multiple cached elements

Tags: jquery, caching, variables, css-selectors, element

In jQuery you can select two elements by id like: $('#elem, #elem2');

BUT

What if you have cached the elem and elem2, and what to apply the same method/function to them both?

i.e.

$elem = $('#elem');
 $elem2 = $('#elem2');

This obviously wont work:

```
$($elem, $elem2)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [add](http://api.jquery.com/add/) method:

```
$elem.add($elem2).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the jquery data api http://docs.jquery.com/Data

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
var element1 = $('#element1'),
    element2 = $('#element2'),
    element3 = $('#element3'),
    element4 = $('#element4');

$([element1[0], element2[0], element3[0], element4[0]]).my_function();
```

and had after some performance testing a way better result than this:

```
element1.add(element2).add(element3).add(element4).my_function();
```